# SQL, OrgNode, Hierarchy

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchy

I have a problem:
Table I:

```
SELECT OrgNode as 'hierarchyid'
, OrgLevel as "non-type '
, UniCODOBJ as 'uniqueidentifier'
, BitREQUIRED as "bit"
, StrField as 'nvarchar (50)'
, StrTITLE_FIELD as 'nvarchar (50)'
, IntCODE_LENGTH as 'int'
OF BOX_HIERARCHY
```

and I have the query:

```
DECLARE @CurrentNode hierarchyid
SELECT @ CurrentNode = OrgNode
OF BOX_HIERARCHY
where uniCODOBJ = 'CBC33732-2E4C-4103-887A-B968E53C0E05';

SELECT OrgNode, OrgNode.ToString ()
, OrgLevel
, uniCODOBJ
, bitREQUIRED
, strField
, strTITLE_FIELD
, intCODE_LENGTH
of BOX_HIERARCHY
where OrgNode.IsDescendantOf (@CurrentNode) = 1
```

but, this query returns:

```
OrgNode OrgNode.string OrgLevel BitRequired
0x78 / 3/1 1
0x7AC0 / 3/1/2 1
0x7AD6 / 3/1/1/3 0
0x7AD6B0 / 3/1/1/1/4 0
0x7AD6B580 / 3/1/1/1/1/5 1
0x7AD6B5AC / 3/1/1/1/1/1/6 1
```

because OrgNode -> 0x78 have uniCODOBJ: CBC33732-2E4C-4103-887A-B968E53C0E05

where is my problem?
direct son is only necessary:

with OrgNode -> 0x78 only have 1 direct children

OrgNode OrgNode.string OrgLevel BitRequired

```
0x78 / 3/1 1
0x7AC0 / 3/1/2 1
```

with OrgNode -> 0x7AC0 with 3 Possible direct children
OrgNode OrgNode.string OrgLevel BitRequired

```
0x7AC0 / 3/1/2 1
0x7AD6 / 3/1/1/3 0
0x7AD6B0 / 3/1/1/1/4 0
0x7AD6B580 / 3/1/1/1/1/5 1
```

my i'm interested to get the query with which to obtain all possible direct children
but that query returns me all relatives children
if I have to go through 3 levels as in the 0x7AD6B5AC case is at level 6, with 3 levels AT LEAST 0x78 and to make the consultation for the 0x78, it returns all me, which I do not care.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution myself:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_CHILD_REPOS] @id uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @hi hierarchyid;
    SELECT @hi = OrgNode FROM BOX_HIERARCHY
    WHERE uniCODOBJ = @id

    SELECT h.OrgNode.ToString() AS OrgNode, h.OrgLevel, h.uniCODOBJ, h.bitREQUIRED,
    strFIELD, t.strARCTAB, t.strNOMOBJ
    FROM BOX_HIERARCHY h
    INNER JOIN tabTABLAS t
    ON h.uniCODOBJ = t.uniCODPAD
    WHERE OrgNode.IsDescendantOf(@hi) = 1
    AND OrgNode <> @hi
    AND OrgLevel <=
    (
        SELECT MIN(OrgLevel)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT h.OrgNode.ToString() AS OrgNode, h.OrgLevel, h.uniCODOBJ, h.bitREQUIRED,
            strFIELD, t.strARCTAB, t.strNOMOBJ
            FROM BOX_HIERARCHY h
            INNER JOIN tabTABLAS t
            ON h.uniCODOBJ = t.uniCODPAD
            WHERE OrgNode.IsDescendantOf(@hi) = 1
            AND OrgNode <> @hi
        ) a
        WHERE bitREQUIRED = 1
    )
    ORDER BY OrgNode

END
```